# Kendo UI datasource filter by comparing fields

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I have a Kendo UI DataSource and I want to filter it by comparing fields.
This is my datasource:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  data: [
    { appointment: "Hairdresser", start: new Date("somedate"), end:  new Date("somedate")},
    { appointment: "Meeting", start: new Date("somedate"), end:  new Date("somedate")},
    { appointment: "Shopping", start: new Date("somedate"), end:  new Date("somedate")}
  ]
});
```

And I want to filter it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM dataSource WHERE start > end;

dataSource.filter({
                "field": "start",
                "operator": "gt",
                "value": ?????
            });
```

How can I achieve this using filters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **not** possible with the built-in filtering. Instead I would suggest you to create a button which  on click will send some extra parameters to the server where you can perform such filtering on your own.

To send additional fields and perform a Read request you can go like this

```
dataSource.read({ myCustomFilter:true });
```

Comment: I suspected this :( I do not want to do the filtering server side because I want to keep the original dataset in context.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do this client-side, I'd suggest using something like lo-dash's [filter](http://lodash.com/docs#filter) method (or, depending on the browsers you need to support, simply the native [Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) implementation) to implement your filter.

You could store all data in an external array and only keep the filtered data in the data source which is bound to the UI (update with [`dataSource.data()`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/framework/datasource#methods-data)):

```
var data = [{
    name: 'barney',
    age: 36,
    start: new Date(2011, 1, 1),
    end: new Date(2012, 1, 1)
}, {
    name: 'fred',
    age: 40,
    start: new Date(2011, 1, 1),
    end: new Date(2010, 1, 1)
}];

var filtered = _.filter(data, function (item) {
    return item.start > item.end;
});

dataSource.data(filtered);
```

Comment: Hi,yes this is something similar to what I ended up with.